# XML Files to listbox + textbox

Tags: c#, xml, textbox, listbox

I know my title is'nt really obvious, but i can't explain myself clearly, sorry.

My application is filling a listbox with data from a xml file, from the `<name>` tag, this part is working, no problems, now, what i want to do is when i click a name on the listbox it loads the `<desc>` field corresponding to the `<name>` field.

Eg: I click the name "john" in my listbox, it have to display in the textbox the corresponding desc.

My current code:

```
foreach (var coordinate in coordinates.Descendants("app"))
            {
                string appName = coordinate.Element("appname").Value;
                string appDesc = coordinate.Element("desc").Value;
                lstApps.Items.Add(appName);
            }
```

I know i could to this using datagrid, but i don't want to for "design" reasons.

I hope i did'nt brainfucked anyone as i am right now !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is the XML content dynamic?  Why not snatch it all into a collection, such as `Dictionary<String,String>` up-front and just have it for ready indexing as selections occur?  You could then use that to load the ListBox _and_ find the `Desc` on-the-fly.

Comment: XML is loaded from a RSA encoded answer wich is long to get (like 10 seconds)
Maybe i should have told that i'm not really good at c# since i'm a web developper :p

Comment: But aren't you paying that penalty anyhow?  Does that preclude my suggested approach?  Perhaps I misunderstand...

Comment: The use of dictionnary seems to be the solution to my problm, however, i don't know how to load the corresponding desc.
Also, can a dictionnary contain more than two strings ? I'll need more later.

Comment: `Dictionary` is a collection of `KeyValuePair` objects.  So two strings, for instance.  If you need more, you could make a dictionary like this:  `Dictionary<String,List<String>>` where you would have a "name" key, and then a list of String that go along.  Or any variation, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example (not meant to be precise):

```
Dictionary<String,String> dict = new Dictionary<String,String>();
foreach (var coordinate in coordinates.Descendants("app"))
    dict.Add(coordinate.Element("appname").Value, coordinate.Element("desc").Value);
foreach (keyValuePair<String,String> kvp in dict)
    lstApps.Items.Add(kvp.Key);
```

When you want the description:

```
String desc = dict[lstApps.SelectedItem.ToString()];  //you might have to adjust this to get the text from the ListBox selected item
```

Comment: Yeah i fixed it myself, but thanks for the exemple, helped me alot :)

Comment: Well, everything is working fine, exept this, my listbox is filled with duplicated datas, totaly randomly.
Like:
name1
name1
name3
name2
name1

The problem is not from my loop

Comment: Is that fill loop happening more than once?  Dictionary<> must have unique keys, so by definition, one pass through it _cannot_ produce duplicates.  Perhaps a `lstApps.Items.Clear()` before the loop is in order.

Comment: Yeah working if i clear the list first, i just don't understand why, thanks again ;p